# Mysql - Inner Join - get the non associate results

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

i need to do a query.
For example, i have products and sub products. Sub products can be associate to products, so i need a query that give me the results of sub products that are not associate to a certain product.
I did a inner join but is not right.

```
SELECT * 
FROM subProducts 
    INNER JOIN products on subProducts.id != products.idSubProduct 
WHERE products.id = $idProduct
```

Thank's

Comment: This has been asked multiple times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863751/why-inner-join-not-equal-hang-forever.  Your query will run for what will seem like forever considering you're trying to link on anything but a match which could be the entire rest of your table for every single row.  I'm guessing you couldn't get this to complete at all depending on how much data you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `outer join` instead with a `null` check:

```
SELECT * 
FROM subProducts 
     LEFT JOIN products on subProducts.id = products.idSubProduct 
         AND products.id = $idProduct
WHERE products.id IS NULL
```

---

There are other ways to do this as well -- `not in` and `not exists` can work similarly.  Here's using `not exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM subProducts s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.idSubProduct = s.id AND p.id = $idProduct
    )
```

Comment: How can i pass the first query to laravel? i don't know use the AND in laravel and doesn't work with where. thank's