# SQL Query not equal rows

Tags: sql

There are two tables **table1** and **table2** i want to join these tables and expect to retrieve rows which are not equal to **table1** as there are rows which are in the both tables.

**Table1**

```
ID   NAME   Dept
 1   B     Finance
 2   R     HR
 3   B     CDU
```

**Table2**

```
ID  PASSPORT
1   Yes
2   No
```

it is not working

```
SELECT table1.ID, table1.NAME, table1.Dept FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON 
TABLE1.ID != TABLE2.ID
```

**Expected Result**

```
  ID   NAME  DEPT 
  3     B     CDU
```

Comment: thanks just edited

Comment: show your expected result

Comment: ok let me edit it

Comment: Try FULL OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN so the columns you're selecting exist

Comment: Do you want values that are exclusively in one table or the other? i.e. only in table1 or only in table2. Or values that are in table1 but not in table2? Or values that are in table2 but not in table1?

Comment: Please show us your expected output.

Comment: This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863751/why-inner-join-not-equal-hang-forever

Comment: let me try  "Jorge Bar Mza"

Comment: checked edited one  Adam

Comment: Abdul mine should work

Comment: i think you already got a answer from @Sachin A

Comment: His answer works but using a subquery increases the processing time unnecessarily. `left join` would be preferrable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a left join to and where clause to grab the values that are only in table1

```
select
  table1.id,
  table1.name,
  table1.Dept
from
  table1
  left join table2 on table2.id = table1.id
where
  table2.id is NULL;
```

**Output for the above Query:**

[image: output]

A left join will insert a null value if the record from the second table cannot be found. So add in the where clause to grab all results that could not be found in the second table.

Here is a better description of using a `left join` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: it is not going to work coz it is going to show all left table rows in table1, please review my expected result

Comment: No it should work. I've been writing SQL for a while it gets what you want just add in the columns you care about.

Comment: Let me try again

Answer (score 1):

Try this query --

```
SELECT ID
    ,NAME
    ,Dept
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM Table2
        WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
        );
```

Comment: `WHERE ID IS NOT NULL` is unnecessary on since it is likely `ID` is a primary key and would always have a value.

Comment: Yes. I didn't know about that so I just took care of it by adding it.

Comment: @Adam - It is needed `NOT IN` will fail when `sub-query` returns any `NULL` value... at least in `Sql Server`

Comment: I was assuming it was a primary key and thus never nullable. He wasn't.

Comment: in the second table it is foreign key Adam, for test i named it as ID

Comment: in your query i did not added not null that was why it was not working Sachin A

Comment: Well if it is a foreign key it would also never be nullable. dope move by me saying primary key lol